# "Only primitive types are supported in this context"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have got this exception in the last line of my code:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

My Code:

```
using (GharardadhaEntities dal = new GharardadhaEntities())
{
    IQueryable<TBL_Gharardad> Gharardadha =
        from record in dal.TBL_Gharardad
        join shenase in Query on record.PK_Shenase equals shenase
        select record;

    var q = (from record in dal.TBL_MabalegheDariaftieMahane
             where record.TBL_Gharardad == Gharardadha.First()
             select record); 

    ulong v = (ulong)Gharardadha.First().MablagheDariaftiKol;// I have got the error on this statement
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What is the type of `record.TBL_Gharardad` and `Gharardadha`?  If they're not primitive types as explained in the message, it will not work.

Comment: TBL_Gharardad is a class that generated by EF.

Comment: Couldn't you compare their id's instead of the objects themselves?  I bet that would fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the problem is `Query`. The exception says that you cannot pass `EnumerableQuery` to Linq-to-entities. If `Query` is `IEnumerable` try to rewrite first query as:

```
IQueryable<TBL_Gharardad> Gharardadha =
    from record in dal.TBL_Gharardad
    where Query.Contains(record.PK_Shenase)
    select record;
```

Comment: Error simply says that you are passing something which cannot be translated to linq-to-entities because it is not basic type. Play with your by commenting joins or where condition until you find it.